# $G$ is a non-abelian group with nontrivial centre $C$. Then the centre of $G/C$ trivial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ is a non-abelian group with nontrivial centre $C$. Then the centre of $G/C$ trivial? I have no idea  please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't true. Take a nonabelian group $G$ of order $p^3$. Its center $C$ has order $p$, so $G/C$ has order $p^2$ and is thus abelian, meaning the center of $G/C$ is $G/C$.

For an example where the center of $G/C$ is neither the identity nor $G/C$ itself, take $G=S_4\times Q_8$, where $S_4$is the symmetric group on 4 elements and $Q_8$ is the group of quaternions.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a non-abelian $p$-group. Such as the Dihedral group with $8$ elements. Then a classic argument relying on the class equation tells us that any $p$-group has non-trivial ceneter. Then $G/Z(G)$ is again a $p$-group and since $G$ was non-abelian $G/Z(G)$ is non-trivial so it must have non-trivial center. In the case that $G=D_8$ then we have $Z(G/Z(G))=G/Z(G)$!

Answer (score 1):

As other have said, this is not true.  I wanted to add to their explanations by showing you some definitions related to your question.

> **Definition.** Let $G$ be a group.  Define a normal series $$1=Z_0\unlhd Z_1 \unlhd \cdots \unlhd Z_i \unlhd \cdots$$ by $Z_0=1$ and $Z_{i+1}/Z_i=Z(G/Z_i)$.  This is the *upper central series* of $G$.  We call a group *nilpotent* if $Z_r=G$ for some $r\in \mathbb{N}$, in which case the lowest such $r$ is the *nilpotency class* of $G$.

So your claim is actually that *no nonabelian group is nilpotent* - since $G/Z(G)$ is nontrivial with a trivial center, the series never terminates.  Of course, if this were true, then we would simply call nilpotent groups abelian, as certainly any abelian group is nilpotent of class $1$.  As Brett and Jacob established, however, this is false.  The smallest counterexample is the Quaternion group, and indeed *any* nonabelian $p$-group is a counterexample.

Note that if your claim is true at *any* point in the upper central series - that is, if $Z_i$ is nonabelian and $1=Z(G/Z_i)$ - then $G$ is not nilpotent.  In fact, the converse is true for Noetherian groups - any non-nilpotent Noetherian group has a centerless normal section.

So, you can think of a nilpotent group as being a group which is "almost" abelian.  In other words, a group with a central series of finite length can't be *too* nonabelian.  I encourage you to read more about these definitions if this seems interesting.